# whats the best way too get data from another list from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have this database:

[image]

what is the best way too loop all teams and get players names?

for example in the html:

Team: superstars
Players: alex, david

i'm having hard time looping the firebase observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your data to be more flat. And to support players being in multiple teams you can create a node that is a reference to `Players` and `Teams`.

```
{
    Players: {
        -Ksegwegwegwg: {
            name: "alex"
        },
        -K43yhwhyehwh: {
            name: "david"
        }
    },
    Team: {
        -Knwgjkwn4333: {
            name: "superstars"
        }
    },
    InTeam: {
        -Kwegbwegwwegw: {
            player: "alex",
            team: "superstars"
        },
        -Kwegbwegwwegw: {
            player: "david",
            team: "superstars"
        }
    }
}
```

You would add to `InTeam` anytime a player joins a team.

Then you can just query as such:

```
const queryObservable = db.list('/InTeam', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'team',
        equalTo: 'superstars' 
    }
});

// Result = [{player: "alex", team: "superstars"}, {player: "david", team: "superstars"}];
```

Comment: in your solution player can be only in one team.